# point to comma macro

Tags: macros

The following macro from wiki

```
\def\pointtocomma #1.#2{#1,#2}
\pointtocomma 123.456 % expands to 123,456
```

is quite useful to change a point separated number to a comma separated number.
However if the number does not have a point, then the macro expansion can cause some error.

Would it be possible to redefine it so that

```
\pointtocomma 1.4 test % expands to 1,4 test
\pointtocomma 1 test % expands to 1 test
```

?

Comment: The error stems from not having a termination token in your parameter text - `\def\pointtocomma#1.#2\relax{..}` (say) as opposed to `\def\pointtocomma#1.#2{..}`. Why not use a typical argument, as in `\pointtocomma{...}`?

Comment: The [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package provides a lot of machinery for tasks like this.

Comment: Or use the `\num` macro from siunitx, it will normalize to dot, but that can be configured from the preamble

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\def\ptc#1{\expandafter\doptc#1\q.\q}
\def\doptc#1.{\ptcremove#1\ifmmode\mathord\fi,}
\def\ptcremove#1\q#2\q{#1}

\ptc{108}
\ptc{1.08}
\ptc{.108}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as expected.
However when I use it to print a dimension it does no longer work e.g. \ptc{\the\textwidth} while \ptc{3.4pt} works

Comment: Now it does. But this is a primitive (and expandable) version. If you don't need expandable version, and you don't care about it being light, you can use `siunitx` and `\num{1.08}` as other have said.

Comment: Maybe you should use `{,}` as a replacement to prevent wrong spacing in math-mode.

Comment: @Skillmon True, done. In case of use in math mode I would leave `.` in the input and change the output to be `,` (this can be done with ``\mathcode`\.=`\,`` if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 3):

The hard way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pointtocomma{\futurelet\next\checkpointordigit}
\def\checkpointordigit{%
  \ifx\next0\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next1\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next2\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next3\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next4\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next5\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next6\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next7\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next8\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next9\let\next\isdigit\else
  \ifx\next.\let\next\iscomma\else
  \let\next\relax
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \next
}
\def\isdigit#1{#1\pointtocomma}
\def\iscomma#1{{,}\pointtocomma}

\begin{document}

\pointtocomma 123.456 % expands to 123,456

\pointtocomma 1.4 test % expands to 1,4 test

\pointtocomma 1 test % expands to 1 test

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a better interface:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pointtocomma}[1]{\point@to@comma#1.\@nil}
\def\point@to@comma#1.#2\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    % no point
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1}%
  {\point@to@comma@aux#1.#2}%
}
\def\point@to@comma@aux#1.#2.{#1{,}#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pointtocomma{123.456} % expands to 123,456

\pointtocomma{1.4} test % expands to 1,4 test

\pointtocomma{1} test % expands to 1 test

\end{document}
```

Of course, it's easier with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\num{123.456} \num{123,456}

\num{1.4} \num{1,4}

\num{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]